# check array key and array value

Tags: php, arrays

i want to make a login system , but in this case i want to create array as username and password

```
<?php
$users = array(
"user1" => "pass" ,
"user2" => "2" ,
"user3" => "pass3d" 

);

if ( isset($_POST['sb']) ) {

$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
/*
foreach ($users as $user => $pass ) {

    if ( $username == $user && $password == $pass ) {
        echo 'login';
        header("Location: ?page=admin");
    }
        else {
        echo 'failed';
        $_SESSION = array();
        header("Location: ?dologin");

    }   

}
*/
?>
```

as you can see i don't using database , i created username and password in array and i need to check it for login

it's not good idea to do this with foreach

it work's with `foreach` but i want to destroy session if login was failed , so if user entered 3th key and value sesseion will be destroy !

i tried to use `in_array` but i can't do this

what is the best way to compare username and passwords

Answer (score 1):

For first i would not save those passwords in plaintext.
A loop is maybe not the best way, i would think of something like this:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
"1" => "Monday",
"2" => "Tuesday",
"3" => "Wednesday"
);
?>
```

We have this array of the first 3 days of the week. If we want to check if the user gave in `1` and `Monday` we could check it like this:

```
<?php
$var1 = $_POST['index'];
$var2 = $_POST['day'];

if (array_key_exists($var1, $array1))//if key exists in the array
    {
        if ($var2 == $array1[$var1])//if the day matches the value of the key in the array
            {
               //Do something
            }
    }
 ?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php